# Retrieving checkbox output from a template and sending it to a secondary view

Tags: python, html, django

I have this template that outputs objects (yoga positions) in a standard blog format of sorts.

Users may upload new yoga positions to the site via a different form and that all works dandily, however...

In the template I've now added a checkbox to every object that will be generated within each "post" and the idea is that the user should be able to select a variety of posts at their leisure (no one wants to do 2,396 yogapositions in one go I've come to realise...) and then hit a submit button, and then get redirected to a new page where the now filtered out posts will be displayed in a js driven "movie clip" with a timer.

The goal is to create a personal yoga/exercise app.

The template looks something like this:

```
{% for res in results %}
<h2 align="center">
  {{ res.name }}
</h2>
<div class=""  align="center">
  <img src="/media/{{ res.image }}" alt="" style="width:100%; border-radius:6px;">
</div>
<h4 style="margin-left:30px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:12px;">
  What it does:
</h4>
<p style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:0px;">
  {{ res.description }}
</p>
<h4 style="margin-left:30px; margin-bottom:0px;">
  How to do it:
</h4>
<p style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:0px;">
  {{ res.instruction }}
</p>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
{% endfor %}
<a href="{% url 'yoga:playhead' %}" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 mt-2 mr-2 mb-2">GO!</a>
```

In my views I've managed to put together these little guys, the former providing the primary list and the latter (hopefully one day) outputting the filtered list:

```
def start_up(request):
    results = YogaModel.objects.all()
    # data = serializers.serialize("json", results, fields=('name', 'image', 'audiofile'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YogaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/yoga/')
    else:
        form = YogaForm()
    return render(request, 'yoga/start.html', {'results': results, 'yoga_stuff':form})


def playhead(request):
    qs = YogaModel.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize("json", qs, fields=('name', 'image', 'audiofile'))
    print('\n{}\n\n{}\n'.format(qs, data))
    context = {
        'data':data,
        'position':qs
        }
    return render(request, 'yoga/doyoga.html', context)
```

I've been thinking about how I could resolve the issue of sending something back to the 2nd view from this template, but my mind draws a blank every time I try to imagine how I should go about it, and subsequently research of the topic leads me to all kinds of dead ends.

It probably doesn't really help that I'm no good at neither coding nor coding terminology.

I should probably mention that I learn from working examples or not at all as per my experience in this, my short career of coding, so please: Be gentle as you unload your wisdom unto me :)

Answer (score 0):

From HTTP, POST data can't be redirected. See this answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

You should use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/).